# Javascript jquery mobile error

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview

I'm using Cordova and sqlite.. I'm able to create and populate a table but when I want to show my results on a html "" like this --> http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/listview/#Thumbnails

I only get this
[screenshot from android device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gz2Yw.png)
[image]

here is my code on Javascript

```
for (var i = 0; i < response.rows.length; i++) 
{
    temp+="<li><a href='#'><img src='../_assets/img/album-bb.jpg'><h2>"+ response.rows.item(i).nombre+"</h2><p>"+response.rows.item(i).idsn+"</p></a></li>";
    //alert(temp);
    lista.innerHTML=temp;
}
```

and my HTML code

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="responsiveid"></ul>
```

Please, where is my mistake?

Comment: `$( "#responsiveid" ).listview( "refresh" );`.

Comment: http://api.jquerymobile.com/listview/#method-refresh

Comment: Thank you I was in a hurry :D